# Batch to Create video .srt Subtitles with right timing

Tags: batch-file, subtitle, srt

Oh boy! I don't know even know what to start with) So, I have a folder with a lot of videos. What I need is to create subtitles with the names of those videos also minding their length to create subtitles in .srt format.

I have already look up some info and copied some code

```
@echo off  
set dirpath=%1 
dir C:\FolderwithVideos /O:S /b /-p /o:gn > "C:\result.txt"
call replacer.bat result.txt ".mp4" ""
exit
```

As a result i got this in result.txt

```
 videoname1
 videoname2
 videoname3
```

What I need is to make them look like this (And of course in the end to create .srt file with the result.)

```
1
00:00:0,000 --> 00:00:25,000
videoname1

2
00:00:25,000 --> 00:00:35,000
videoname2

3
00:00:35,000 --> 00:00:55,000
videoname3
```

Hope I got everything, please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How long do each of the subtitles need to be? Their durations vary in your example.

Comment: Well, every video has a different duration, so it is necessary first to determine the duration of every video in the folder, and then to create sequent timeline. so i guess everytime a piece of code should check every video's length

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31864121/1683264) will give you some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using VBS to get the video length of each video files (using [Folder.GetDetailsOf method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and to `sum` the lengths for the timers in the `.srt` file (using the [FormatDateTime Function)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

This script get the name of the videos in your result.txt file (so you have to include your code in this `BAT` or run the bat, that generate it, before.

I already include it in my code but with `REM` before. So remove the `REMs` if needed.

The result is displayed on the CMD and writing in the file `Output.srt`(In the same directory of the BAT file)

BuildSrt.bat

```
@echo off&cls

::The Path of your Videos files

set "$VideoPath=C:\FolderwithVideos"

::If you want your Code in this BAT remove the REMs Below :

rem dir "%$VideoPath%" /O:S /b /-p /o:gn > "C:\result.txt"
rem call replacer.bat result.txt ".mp4" ""

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a $Count=1
set "$Timer=00:00:00"


(for /f "delims=" %%a in (result.txt) do (
  call:getVideolength "%%a.mp4"
  for /f "delims=" %%x in ('cscript //nologo getvideolength.vbs') do (
       call:SumTime !$Timer! %%x
       for /f "delims=" %%y in ('cscript //nologo SumTime.vbs') do set "$NewTimer=%%y"
       echo !$Count!
       echo !$Timer!,000 --^> !$NewTimer!,000
       echo %%a
       Set $Timer=!$NewTimer!
  )
  set /a $Count+=1
))>Output.srt

echo Done !!!
type Output.srt
pause
exit/b

:GetVideoLength
(echo dim objShell
echo dim objFolder
echo dim objFolderItem
echo set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application"^)
echo set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("%$videoPath%"^)
echo set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(%1^)
echo dim objInfo
echo objInfo = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 27^)
echo wscript.echo objinfo)>GetVideoLength.vbs
exit/b


:SumTime
echo wscript.echo FormatDateTime(CDate("%1"^) + CDate("%2"^),3^) >SumTime.vbs
exit/b
```

This will create a file `Output.srt` like this :

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 01:28:28,000
Film1
2
01:28:28,000 --> 02:49:39,000
Film2
3
02:49:39,000 --> 04:45:25,000
Film3
```

Comment: it works for videofiles named completely in english and if it has any sort of symbols such as ☺ or ♪ ♣ in its name or if it's in another language then it shows Microsoft VBScript error.

Comment: SO is an English forum ! And in your question i can't see anywhere that you''ll work with unicode filename. I think my answer resolve your problem ! Now its is another question to resolve this unicode problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely forgot about unicode, anyways, Thank you very much for your help!